# Display tables of a database in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, awt, resultset

I'm working on a java application, and I want to display the list of the tables in a Mysql database, I searched on the net and I found that "SHOW TABLES FROM [DB]" is the appropriate request, but how can I dispaly the result of this last on a java swing/awt application, 
PS : I tried to put the result of the request on a resultset,

`res = sta.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES FROM sinpec ");`

but it doesnt work ...

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Read the `resultset` in a loop and pass the values to an appropriate view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this query:-

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "DATABASE_NAME"
```

Comment: If this is one line answer, better enter comment for it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/sql-query-to-find-all-table-on-database-mysql-sqlserver.html) blog, you could use the following statement:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table' AND table_schema='test';
```

Which seems to have a similar effect to that of `SHOW TABLES`.

This should work with the result result that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/09/print-tables-details-in-schema-jdbc.html) may help you. Basically you can use `DatabaseMetaData` class to full fill your task.

```
public static String SCHEMA_NAME="${YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME}";

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  //create and setup your database and get db connection
  DataBase db = new DataBase();
  db.init();

  try {
   Connection con = db.getConnection();
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = con.getMetaData();

    String tableType[] = {"TABLE"};

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   ResultSet result = metaData.getTables(null,SCHEMA_NAME,null,tableType);
    while(result.next())
    {
     String tableName = result.getString(3);

     builder.append(tableName + "( ");
     ResultSet columns = metaData.getColumns(null,null,tableName,null);

     while(columns.next())
     {
      String columnName = columns.getString(4);
      builder.append(columnName);
      builder.append(",");
     }
     builder.deleteCharAt(builder.lastIndexOf(","));
     builder.append(" )");
     builder.append("\n");
     builder.append("----------------");
     builder.append("\n");


    }

   System.out.println(builder.toString());


  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution it shows all the tables

```
try {
    DbMd = myconn.getMetaData();
    Rslt = DbMd.getTables(null, null, "%", null);

    while (Rslt.next()) {
        System.out.println(Rslt.getString(3));
    } 
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```