# Show tables returns "Show tables handled."

Tags: sql, oracle

So i want to get list of all tables in current database. I tried with this command:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

but it is printing only the string: `Show tables handled.` and nothing else.

I tried this: [Display tables of a database in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843344/display-tables-of-a-database-in-java) But the query returns the following error (yes, cause and action are empty):

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What do theese output mean? What should i do in this case?

Comment: How is this related to java ?

Comment: The linked question is for MySQL. If you're using Oracle, then you shouldn't blindly follow advice for MySQL.

Comment: There is no `show tables;` in Oracle.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes i see now... looks like i overlooked this

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what is used in Oracle? If you know that you should write answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Metadata queries for Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general010.htm#ADMIN11564) are different. What you are looking for is probably somethink like this:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
     FROM USER_ALL_TABLES u
     WHERE u.nested='NO' 
     AND (u.iot_type is null or u.iot_type='IOT');
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is Oracle, then

```
select * from user_tables;
```

For all objects (procedures, views, ... - tables included), see

```
select * from user_objects;
```

Both of those results contain a lot of columns; pick the ones you're interested in.